# Selecting unique lines based on two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I've been trying to figure out a way to select lines that are unique based on the values of two columns. For example, here is a sample/example of my file:

```
s      r
10    12
10    13
14    10
10    12
14    10
12    10
```

And this is what I want my output to look like:

```
s      r
10    12
10    13
14    10
```

I've tried to use this code

```
SELECT * FROM `message` WHERE (`s_id`=$b_id or 'r_id'=$b_id) GROUP BY 
r_id
```

However, it only select 10,12  10,11 and i also needed 14,10 i mean the third row

in this case $b_id is obtained from session and it may be s or r

Comment: SELECT * FROM `message` group by s,r

Comment: What do you mean by "i also needed 9,10"?

Comment: @shuddh i was mistake i remove it

Comment: You appear to have no PRIMARY KEY, which may prove problematic in due course

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use DISTINCT
`SELECT DISTINCT s_id,r_id FROM`message`WHERE (`s_id`=$b_id or 'r_id'=$b_id);`
always try to specify which column needed instead of * (all) it improve the performance

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
select distinctrow s_id,r_id from table where s_id = 10 or r_id = 10
```

or else use "having" clause and group by both columns

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Comment: Thanks forgot the keyword is distinctrow

Comment: Nearly. DISTINCTROW and DISTINCT are synonyms. Neither of which is a function.

Comment: I know that, but this will solve the problem he has currently. Distinctrow can be used of multiple columns. so it will work. otherwise, a workaround can be done. by using inner queries.

Comment: @Shuddh along with distinct row if 1,2 row is find than row with 2,1 should be excluded

Comment: @shabirullah no that will not happen

Comment: @shabirullah Your original comment is misleading. DISTINCT is always applied to ALL the columns in the SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

After two days struggling i am succeeded in finding out solution to my problem

```
SELECT * FROM `message` WHERE s=$b_id or r=$b_id AND (r and 
s)<>(s_ and r) GROUP BY s,r
```